# Adding System Image to navigation bar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I'm trying to move from storyboards to coding programmatically. I'm trying to add a barbuttonitem to my navigation bar. However, I don't want to use my own images, I want to use the default system images, such as "magnifyingglass.circle".

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "magnifyingglass.circle") , style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

However, nothing is added to my navigation bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong `UIImage` initializer. The one you are trying to use requires a full path to an image file. You want `UIImage(systemName:)`.

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle") , style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```